# extract all columns header

Tags: php, socrata, soda

I need to extract all columns header with SODA Api.

I didn't found a solution with API, so I create this code.
But in some cases the title of the column is different from the column api name...

There's a better solution?

```
//return the Dataset Columns Header
public function getDatasetColumnsHeader($dataset) {

    $file = "https://www." . $this->root_url . "/resource/" . $dataset . ".csv";
    $f = fopen($file, 'r');
    $line = fgets($f);
    fclose($f);

    return explode(",", $line);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found the solution:

```
//return the Dataset Columns Header
public function getDatasetColumnsHeader2($dataset) {

    $url = "https://www." . $this->root_url . "/resource/" . $dataset . ".csv";
    $header = get_headers($url, 1);

    $return = array();
    eval('$return = ' . $header["X-SODA2-Fields"] . ';');

    return $return;

}
```